# how to hide wordpress submenu page

Tags: wordpress

i have want to hide some subpages from my plugin menu, my plugin menu code is like

```
add_menu_page($page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $parent_slug, "addProduct", Null, 21);
    add_submenu_page($parent_slug, $page_title . " ", "", $capability, $parent_slug, "");
// Product section
    add_submenu_page($parent_slug, $page_title . " - Add Products", "Add Product", $capability, $parent_slug . "-add-product", "addProduct");
    add_submenu_page($parent_slug, $page_title . " - View Products", "View Products", $capability, $parent_slug . "-view-product", "viewProducts");
    add_submenu_page($parent_slug, $page_title . " - Edit Products", "Edit Products", $capability, $parent_slug . "-edit-product", "editProduct");
    add_submenu_page($parent_slug, $page_title . " - Delete Products", "Edit Products", $capability, $parent_slug . "-edit-product", "editProduct");
```

i want to hide edit products and delete product page from my plugin menu, if i keep empty menu title field it shows gap in menu.

can you guys tell me how to do it or should i have direct call to these files

Answer (score 9):

Set to null - will hide menu link

```
add_submenu_page(null, $page_title . " - Delete Products", "Edit Products", $capability, $parent_slug . "-edit-product", "editProduct");
```

Comment: But it will not high light parent menu when sub menu page is opened

Comment: This technique doesn't work anymore with PHP 8.2+, it ends up with
`
Deprecated: strpos(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 7241

Deprecated: str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type array|string is deprecated in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2187

Deprecated: strip_tags(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-header.php on line 36
`